# Array java mostra itens especificos

Tags: java, eclipse

Olá , pessoal estou com uma duvida por exemplo  possuo o Array A {1,2,3,4,5} , faço outro array B {1,2,3} com os itens que desejo exclui do array A, e mostrar os itens que sobraram ex o 4 eo 5 , porém estou com parando um if dentro de um  for e a resposta sai completamente loca , algume poderia me ajudar ?

Não posso usar arraylist.

### ex: A = {1,2,3,4,5}

novo array com os itens que desejo que não sejam exibidos :

### B = {1,2,3}

dentro do for  com parar e mostrar apenas os itens diferentes

### 4 e 5

Segue abaixo o código que eu tentei

```
int qtdpessoas ;
        int exclui ;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        qtdpessoas = sc.nextInt();
        int idpessoa [] = new int [qtdpessoas];


        for (int i = 0; i < idpessoa.length; i++) {

            idpessoa[i]= sc.nextInt();
            }

        exclui = sc.nextInt();
        int paraexcluir [] = new int [exclui];

        for (int i = 0; i < paraexcluir.length; i++) {
            paraexcluir[i]= sc.nextInt();
            }

        for (int i = 0; i < idpessoa.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < paraexcluir.length; j++) {
                if (idpessoa[i]!= paraexcluir[j]) {
                System.out.println(idpessoa[i]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Já tentou algo? Se tiver, pode postar o código?

Comment: sim , vou reeditar aqui e se tu puder da uma olhada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obter o resultado que você deseja faça as seguintes alterações no seu código:

- No `if` verifique se os elementos são iguais, e caso sejam, pule para a próxima iteração do laço;
- Adicione um `else if` que verifique se está no último elemento e caso esteja utilize o `System.out.println`, assim você terá testado todos os elementos e esta condição só será satisfeita se nenhum elemento for igual.

---

O seu `if` ficará mais ou menos assim:

```
if (idpessoa[i] == paraexcluir[j]) {
  break;
} else if (j == (paraexcluir.length - 1)) {
  System.out.println(idpessoa[i]);
}
```